# PHP. Сравнить два пераметра и найти нужный

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Задача сравнить два параметра. к примеру есть _GET параметр и через него передается что-то плохое и к примеру есть массив с плохими данными для сравнения, как их сравнить?
У меня есть вот такой код, но он неработает почему то:

```
// AntiLFI 
$badSymbols[] = "/etc/";
$badSymbols[] = "/passwd/";
$badSymbols[] = "/proc/";
$badSymbols[] = "/self/";
$badSymbols[] = "/environ/";
// AntiSHELL functions
$badSymbols[] = "/passthru/";
$badSymbols[] = "/exec/";
$badSymbols[] = "/shell/";
$badSymbols[] = "/open/";
$badSymbols[] = "/load_file/";
$badSymbols[] = "/system/";
$badSymbols[] = "/show_source/";


if ( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET) ) {

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

        for ($i=0; $i < count($badSymbols); $i++) { 

            if (preg_match($value, $badSymbols[$i])) {
                echo "+---------------------------------+";
                echo "| Please, stop hacking!           |";
                echo "+---------------------------------+";
                die("You are terminated!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще, в таких простых правилах, менее ресурсоёмко использовать strpos.

Answer (score 2):

Вся проблема в том, что в неправильном порядке передаете аргументы функции `preg_match`.
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php
Сначала надо передать регулярное выражение, потом обрабатываемый текст. У Вас наоборот. В остальном код правильный.

Почти правильный.

Никто так регулярные выражения не использует. Весь этот код можно заменить таким:

```
$re = "/etc|passwd|...|show_source/i";
if ( preg_match( $re, $value) ) die( "Bad request" );
```

Или более читаемая запись регулярного выражения:

```
$re = <<<HEREDOC
/
etc |
passwd |
... |
show_source
/ix
HEREDOC;
```

Comment: Использует, когда сет правил есть где-то в массиве. Собственно как у автора. А если злоумышленник может правила подменить, то тут уже эта защита не спасла. :D

Comment: @SlyDeath надеюсь я не совру, но если использовать только функцию прег_матч и главное, чтобы хотя бы один шаблон сматчился (как здесь), то абсолютно любые регулярные выражения в массиве можно собрать в большую альтернативу. И это совсем ни капли не усложнит понимание, ведь heredoc и Х-запись никто не отменял :-)

Comment: Приведу в пример парсер. В массив забиваются бренды, которые нужно парсить. Эти бренды проще редактировать когда они по-одиночке. Плюс браться могут из базы, где их вбивает явно не регуляркой бабушка Клава. Плюс ко всему простую регулярку легко сделать оптимизированной. Если начать городить, то можно уйти в "жадность" и тогда исполнение регулярки будет очень ресурсоёмким. Дело оно такое, тонкое. Почитайте книжку какую-нибудь про оптимизацию регулярок, много нового узнаете. Я в шоке был. :)

Comment: @SlyDeath спасибо :-) обязательно почитаю :-) но точки возврата не будут создаваться. Ведь имея кучу регулярок собранных в одну альтернативу движок будет по очереди применять эти выражения к каждому литералу, начиная с первого. То есть все то же самое, как и в одиночном выражении. То есть смысл такой кратко: если одиночное выражение не падает в катастрофический бэктрейсинг, то и в составе большой альтернативы оно этого не сделает.

Comment: дело не в количестве итераций, а как регулярное выражение обрабатывается. Два, на вид почти одинаковых выражения, могут различаться в скорости на очень много времени. Например если там ещё и жадные квантификаторы есть, например звёздочка. Но в этой задаче, я думаю, **strpos** хватило бы. :)

Comment: @SlyDeath не буду спорить, ибо уже не понимаю о чем спор.

Comment: @ReinRaus, "абсолютно любые регулярные выражения в массиве можно собрать в большую альтернативу" - а php обратные ссылки не умеет что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо. Правильное замечание. Обратные ссылки и рекурсию просто так не получится объединить. Придется именовать группы уникальными именами или использовать относительные ссылки ( начиная с пхп 5.2.2).

Comment: мне удобен массив потому, что можно добавлять или удалять фразы

Answer (score 1):

Delimiter (в вашем случае это прямой слэш /) preg_match'a должен быть внутри самого preg_match, а не в шаблоне, который хранится строкой в переменной. 
И в конце правила неплохо бы указать, что правило регистронезависимо и мультилайново, для этого используются модификаторы "i" и "s". Пример:

```
$badSymbol = "etc";
$value = "this etc fail";

if (preg_match("/$badSymbol/is", $value)) {
    echo "+---------------------------------+";
    echo "| Please, stop hacking!           |";
    echo "+---------------------------------+";
    die("You are terminated!");
}
```

Comment: А что будет, если `$badSymbol = "/etc/"` ?

Comment: Регулярка будет искать не "etc", а "/etc/". Только экранировать слэши надо. Но я, чтобы не заморачиваться, обычно делемитеры делаю тильдами - `preg_match("~$badSymbol~is", $value)` Тогда об экранировании думать не надо.

Comment: Блин, а нельзя было просто сказать автору, что он перепутал порядок следования аргументов, передаваемых прег_матч. ТС передавал сначала текст, потом регулярку. Надо наоборот.

Comment: Ну так и напиши ответ с тильдами...

Comment: Просто экранировать надо :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus чёт я не обратил внимания. :) Но и моё верно. :)

Answer (score 0):

SlyDeath прав:

```
preg_match("/$badSymbol/is", $value)
```

Либо же попробуйте `?param=/etc/`

Comment: у меня не работает такой вариант

Comment: Ваш код "работоспособен". Не могу сказать почему он не работает у Вас